# Generating SQL Queries for Inserting random codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, generator

Sometimes I have to insert so many random codes into the database for discounts, campaigns, etc. To do this I created an excel sheet to generate SQL codes. But this is taking too much time.

For example, the query down below is just for inserting one code. I want to generate many different queries (sometimes thousands) by just changing the code field.

I could not find a good tool for that yet and would appreciate any help.

```
INSERT INTO COUPON (ID,TENANTID,CODE,COUPONDESCRIPTION,EFFECTIVEDATE,EFFECTIVEDAYCOUNT,OPERATIONAMOUNT,OPERATIONAMOUNTCURRENCYID,ACCOUNTINGAMOUNT,ACCOUNTINGAMOUNTCURRENCYID,EFECTIVEOPERATIONAMOUNT,EFECTIVEOPERATIONAMOUNTCURRENCYID,EFECTIVEACCOUNTINGAMOUNT,EFECTIVEACCOUNTINGAMOUNTCURRENCYID,RATIO,USAGECOUNTBYCUSTOMER,USAGECOUNTBYCOUPON,BULKCOUPON,BULKCOUPONCOUNT,COUPONTYPE,VOUCHERINDEPENDENTCOUPON,STATUS,EXPIRATIONDATE,COUPONCODEGENERATORTYPEID,PRINTCOUNT,LEGACYGIFTCHECKID,LEGACYADVANTAGECODEID,MIGRATIONCOMPLETED,CONTEXTID,CONTEXTMODULEID) 
select NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_COUPONID,4,'**CODE**','DESCRIPTION','2021-12-17 00:00:00.000',365,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'0.00000000',0,1,0,0,0,1,0,'2022-03-15 23:59:00.000',0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,8
```

Comment: write a script which get CODE list from a table and generate automatically these queries?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what is the format of the random codes?

Comment: Using MS Sql server and the codes are just unique random codes that I generate like ABC123

Comment: Any programming language can generate such codes even Excel VBA to build an .sql script or connect to DB and run the append queries. You could even create a stored function to be called in `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Back in 2019 I've written a blog post about generating random strings in SQL Server that I think you might find helpful in this situation. Enjoy. [A more controllable random string generator function for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/10/a-more-controllable-random-string-generator-function-for-sql-server/)